# How do I embed CRLF or other unprintable characters in my shell script?

Tags: shell, whitespace, sh, non-printing-characters

My boss came to me with a question about how to embed a CRLF sequence into his shell script (for piping through some sort of `netcat` or `telnet` stuff he's doing) in a reasonably portable and robust way.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming POSIX is a good baseline for "portable enough",

```
printf "\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for him:

```
#!/bin/sh
crlf="$(echo xy | tr xy '\r\n')"
```

... but I'm open to other comments.  It's certainly fine with modern versions of GNU `tr` and `bash`.

Comment: (I'm tossing this out in the spirit of Jeff Atwood's recent posting: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: My mistake, need the double quotes around $(...) to preserve that (but worked in my test case and in  his usage because the echo command was adding the \n back).